# What web application allows me to watch English-language movies in Germany?

Tags: webapp-rec

Does anyone know of a (legal) web application that would enable me in Berlin, Germany to view any movie including current popular movies over the Internet via subscription or pay-per-view?

Comment: You can do that using a proxy service.

Comment: The question did say "(legal)" and proxies will violate **someone's** terms of service. Whether the laws, treaties, and licenses are moral I make no comment.

Comment: and you can't really enjoy the movie.. it's very very slow... (a friend told me.. I never tried it :P)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to move to USA if you want that, because unfortunately Europe (or maybe the rest of the world) is not really ready for that yet.

Comment: whoa, people outside the USA watch movies too?

Comment: @eds yes.. unfortunately we do... but not online yet :D